# Bootstrap Carousel com dois itens na vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

O desafio é o seguinte: Fazer um [Carousel, usando o Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), que exiba dois itens por vez, alinhados verticalmente. Segue um esboço da ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei alguns exemplos de Carousel usando múltiplos itens, mas não alinhados verticalmente.

http://www.bootply.com/94444

Tentei implementar e não consegui.

Alguém da uma força?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar este plugin que resolve seu problema:

https://github.com/tutorialdrive/Bootstrap-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel

Comment: Olá Otto, tente complementar um pouco mais a resposta. As respostas por link podem sair do ar e invalidar sua resposta para outras pessoas que pesquisem sobre o mesmo tema.

Comment: beleza mestre @Caputo

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei um `<div class="row">` para resolver esse problema.

[image]

Trecho do código para o 7º item:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/993399/fff&amp;text=7_1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/339933/fff&amp;text=7_2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo e código: http://www.bootply.com/SV7GR796fg

Comment: Pelo que vi no exemplo esta na horizontal não na vertical

Comment: @Otto está parcialmente correto desde que todos os itens sigam a implementação do item 7. Parcialmente porque eu expliquei na pergunta: "exiba dois itens por vez alinhados verticalmente". O que o pessoal ta colocando são dois elementos dentro de um mesmo item. Isso não fica legal, pois o back-end vai fazer o loop em cima do elemento item.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar as técnicas de grid dentro dos itens que o Carousel funciona corretamente.

### [Exemplo](http://www.bootply.com/JHZ3o6w1Ri)

Comment: O comentário que fiz na resposta do Giuliano serve pro teu exemplo também, mas MUITO obrigado pela foça, e se ainda assim souber como me ajudar eu agradeço em dobro. :)